# Facing Problem with uploading a file in Github in Ubuntu Platform

Tags: github

Today I was for the first time Uploading any file in Github! I created a new branch in a certain repository and after whenever I was committed for the first time and then this message is shown in the terminal and tell me to run the two command to know my identity, as they didn't figure out my identity. I was Uploading my file from my personal Laptop. After that whenever I checked the repository I saw that my branch is committing by another person, The person is the last person before me whoever also commit in the same repository, but he doesn't have to do anything with my laptop anyhow. Whatever I ran the two command what it was told or instructed in the terminal.

The Terminal Message:

[image]

But there is no effective result. Do you face this kind of problem whenever uploading any file for the first time in the Github from Ubuntu?

P.S. I am a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS user by the way ...

Comment: When you run `git config --get-regexp user.*` from within your git repository's local directory, are your user name and email address shown correctly?

Comment: (edit) what do you get with `git config --get user.name` now?

Comment: I got this whenever I run `git config --get-regexp user.* ` command @Byte Commander
`user.email example@domainname.com`
`user.name SRSourav`



 and taifwa I got it when i run `git config --get user.name`
SRSourav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed by the command's output, you are trying to commit or push without having told the `git` tool on this computer what your details are; as such it refuses to operate.

You *must* run:

```
git config --global user.name "Salman Sourav"
git config --global user.email "your@email.addr"
```

Note that the email address could equally well be a URL or a string of characters - git does not care.

You must also ensure that you get a successful (empty, no errors) feedback from the commands. Amend question if you do not.

Comment: Thanks taifwa. Successfully Solve the problem according to your guideline.

Comment: YW. Please mark the answer as "Accepted" using the green tick to the left of the answer !